# Aura Components Specialist: Step 3: Completed but tiles do not display data?

Tags: aura-iteration, superbadges

I've just completed step 3 of the Aura Components Specialist superbadge however the tiles for the boat search results just display an empty block on the page.  Not sure why this is happening.  I've tried changing a few different markup attributes within the **BoatSearchResults** component but have not had any success.

This issue didn't prevent me from completing the challenge, however I would like to actually be able to view the images and boats since that is the ultimate goal of this step.  I am almost positive it has to do with the way I am calling the image URL in the **BoatTile.cmp**. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

> BoatSearchResults.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="BoatSearchResults" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="boats" type="Boat__c[]" description="Boat Search Results"/>
<aura:attribute name="resultsMessage" type="String" description="" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedBoatTypeId" type="String" default="" description="" />
<aura:method name="search" action="{!c.doSearch}" access="global" description="search boats">
    <aura:attribute name="boatTypeId" type="String" default="{!v.selectedBoatTypeId}"/>
</aura:method>
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.boats))}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.boats}" var="boat">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="horizontal-medium">
                <c:BoatTile boat="{!boat}" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                No boats found
            </div>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:layout>
```

> BoatTile.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="boat" access="public" type="Boat__c"/>
<lightning:button class="tile" >
    <div style="{!'background-image:url(\'' + v.boat.Picture__c + '\')'}" class="innertile">
        <div class="lower-third">
            <h1 class="slds-truncate">{!v.boat.Contact__r.Name}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning:button>
```

> BoatTile.css

```
.THIS.tile {
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 220px;
padding: 1px !important;
```

}

```
.THIS .innertile {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

```
.THIS .lower-third {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
padding: 6px 8px;
```

}

> Output **Lighting Page**

[image]

> Output **App Page**
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my apex class (BoatSearchResults) I had included the Geolocation__c field as part of the query.  The result of this was that the callback function would always error out unless I converted the return to a JSON string then parsed the string from the component's controller.

Given that the requirements do not outline including the Geolocation in the getBoats() method I walked all this back, then replaced JSON.stringify(response.getReturnvalue()) with response.getReturnvalue() in the BoatSearchResults helper and voila, pictures!

[image]

The lesson here is to only do what is asked.  No more, no less.